# Finding Only numbers between specific range in cell contain text string

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a cell A2 containing following Text string in google sheet.

> UAE Vacancy - Collections Field agents. Location - Dubai, Abu Dhabi Work profile- banking collections background outdoor field. Age- Below 30 years. Salary - AED 5500 + quarterly incentive and yearly bonus. Minimum 1-year of experience in collections is required in the UAE Banking industry. Candidates meeting the criteria, share their resume on
> test@test.com
> with subject 'Field agent' Reference -
> from UAE Jobs #uaejobs #bankjobs #collectionagency #dubaijobs #hireinuae

Now in Cell B2 I want to extract salary which is 5500 a numeric value. i tried to figure it out with is number but it is not working.
How can i extract numbers in next cell.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT($A2, "[0-9]{3,}"))
```

This will extract the first number with 3 or more digits.

See on [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V-JKoDEleKHfP5VctjaySyq5A7Gc5dCwx6-ZxEc4uFQ/edit?usp=sharing)